# How can I make GHCI recognize working directory changes?

Tags: haskell, filesystems, ghci, haskell-turtle

I am experimenting with using ghci+Turtle as my interactive shell instead of bash.  So far it's working pretty well!
But I'd really like Turtle's `cd` function to change ghci's working directory, the way ghci command `:cd` does.

Let's say I load ghci and turtle in `/home`

```
λ> pwd
FilePath "/home"
λ> :show paths
current working directory: 
  /home
module import search paths:
  .
λ> :cd /tmp/
λ> pwd
FilePath "/tmp"
λ> :show paths
current working directory: 
  /tmp
module import search paths:
  .
λ>
```

So far so good: changing the directory with ghci's `:cd` also changes Turtle's working directory.
But the other way is not true:

```
λ> cd "/home"
λ> pwd
FilePath "/home"
λ> :show paths
current working directory: 
  /tmp
module import search paths:
  .
λ>
```

This means that if I change directories with Turtle, I can't use `:load` or `:script` or take advantage of ghci's tab completion.
I can just always use `:cd` instead of `cd`, but because `:cd` is a ghci command, it can't be called from a function or composed in any way.

What would it take to make a `cd` function that talks to ghci?  I think I need to do something like
write my own wrapper `cd` that that somehow changes the environment.
I'm not sure what that looks like, since I can't invoke `:cd` in my `cd` wrapper.
I'm guessing I need to use the ghc API?  I can't find anything obvious.

EDIT:  I found a similar problem exists when I try changing the ghci prompt with [:set prompt-function](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:set%20prompt-function).  If you put the following in your ghci.conf:

```
:module + Turtle
:set prompt-function \libs n -> (\wd -> encodeString wd ++ "> ") <$> pwd
```

The prompt won't change working directories with `cd`, but will with `:cd`.  Using something like `:set prompt "%w > "` works the same way.
My best guess is that ghci keeps a completely separate filesystem module from the user-space module somehow.  I may have to dig into ghci source to figure out what's going on.

It's not limited to Turtle, `Filesystem.setWorkingDirectory` shows the same behavior as `Turtle.cd`.

Comment: I think this question is basically “Why does `Filesystem.setWorkingDirectory` not affect the module search path in ghci (like `:cd` does) and how can I change this?”

Comment: Well that's part of what I'm confused about.  Filesystem.getWorkingDirectory (and Turtle.pwd, and System.Directory.getCurrentDirectory) all return different values in the ghci repl than they return "inside" ghci as exposed by `:set prompt-function` and I think by `:paths`, although it's not clear to me what value exactly `:paths` means when it reports "working directory".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue while developing shh. I've worked around this by providing a `cd` function that sets `PWD` as well as changing the directory, and using a `prompt-function` which reads that variable.

Minimal example..

```
:set prompt-function \_ _ -> getEnv "PWD"
```

```
cd :: FilePath -> IO ()
cd p = do
    setCurrentDirectory p
    a <- getCurrentDirectory
    setEnv "PWD" a
```